# DocuSign : Add the Dynamic Content to DocuSign Server template

Tags: docusignapi

We are generating the Dynamic Content(HTML) into the RTF file (pdf). Add that file in to the envelope.
We wanted to Add the single check box required and Hyperlink for Terms and conditions pdf. We auto replace but the check box is mark as not required and Hyperlink also not working.

For that we are planning to create server templates where Hyperlink is working, and add our Dynamic Content i.e. RTF file into that templates.

I'm not sure if it is possible. It will helpful if you share any article or solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found work around for this.
I have created DocuSign document custom field of type Text Field.
In Initial value Added the text to display on Hyperlink.
In Tooltip added the link
Added the Auto place Text : \link{r}\

Then in my dynamic content used that Auto place text.
Which act as a Hyperlink.

Instead of Check box used Radio button with required property

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not support hyperlinks in documents to be reviewed/signed.

DocuSign does have a "[Supplemental Document](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-send-supplements)" feature that can be used to include additional documents that will only be shown to the signer when they want to see them.

DocuSign also has a feature that enables you to send HTML with additional markup that can include:

- Tabs (fields) defined within the HTML document source
- Sections of the document can be marked to be folded/unfolded by the signer. These are called "Smart Sections"

This type of HTML document is part of the "Responsive Signing / Smart Sections" feature. Check out [*all* of the documents about the feature in the DevCenter guides.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview)